# How to use "csvread" when the contents in the file have different formats?

Tags: matlab, file-io, csv

I have a .csv file and the format is shown below:

mapping.csv

```
5188.40811,TMobileML
5131.40903,TMobileGregsapt
5119.40791,TMobileJonsapartment
5123.40762,TMobileRedhat
```

i want to store it in an 4 by 2 array, when i have a value such as `5131.40903`(this is a 'string' not 'int'), i want to find the mapping relation which is `TMobileGregsapt`. But i meet two problem, the first is i can't use `csvread('mapping.csv')`, it will have some error:
(I think the problem might be `5131.40903` will be `int` when i use csvread, but `TMobileGregsapt` is a string...)

```
??? Error using ==> dlmread at 145
Mismatch between file and format string.
Trouble reading number from file (row 1, field 2) ==> TMobi

Error in ==> csvread at 52
    m=dlmread(filename, ',', r, c);
```

even though i use `dlmread('cell4.csv', ',')`, it still have some error:

```
??? Error using ==> dlmread at 145
Mismatch between file and format string.
Trouble reading number from file (row 1, field 2) ==> TMobi
```

The second problem is how can i finding the mapping relation in easy way, the naive method is using a forloop to find the position of array.

Thanks for your help:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both csvread and dlmread only work for numeric data.  Something like this should work for you

```
out=textread('tmp.csv', '%s', 'whitespace',',');
nums =  out(1:2:end);
strs =  out(2:2:end);
% find index of 'TMobileGregsapt'
ind = find(strcmp('TMobileGregsapt',strs));
nums(ind)
```

Comment: What is the type of `nums` and `strs`? A string or a char array? Since i can't use `str2num(nums)`...

Answer (score 2):

Another answer that will work if you have mixed text/numeric csv but you either don't know what the format is, or it's heterogeneous, use the 'csv2cell' function from: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20836-csv2cell

```
c = csv2cell( 'yourFile.csv', 'fromfile');
```

`c(1, :)` will give your headers and `c(2:end, k)` will give you each of the columns (sans the header), `for k = 1:size(c, 2)`