# Matlab - How to read values from a text file?

Tags: matlab

I am aware that my question may seem similar to others having already been posted. However, I have browsed through answers to apparently close questions, but still couldn't do what I want. Hence, I am asking mine again.

I have a text file (data.txt) of this type.

```
StudentA 10

StudentB 5

StudentC 3
...
```

The data in a same row is separated by a tab.

How can I read only values (that means only the numbers 10, 5, 3, etc.) into Matlab and ignore StudentA, StudentB, etc.?

I did the following.

```
fid=fopen('grades.txt','r');

m=fscanf(fid, '%d');
```

But what Matlab showed was:

```
m =

     []
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
fid = fopen('grades.txt','r');
A = textscan(fid,'%s %d','Delimiter','\r\n');
A = A{1};
```

It should work in your case.

Comment: To ignore the "students" column, you can specify `%*s` instead of `%s`.

Comment: Hi there, the correct code is "A = textscan(fid,'%*s %d','Delimiter')". Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10629691/2216369), which deals with a simmilar situation. In the question the file format is:

```
1 2 3 sometext
4 5 6 somemoretext
etc...
```

The solution proposed uses `textread` to read and tokenized the elements, and then converts them back to a matrix with some indexing logic. This should also work for your case.

Comment: Why not mark this question as a duplicate then?

Comment: @EitanT *shrugs* I could do, but fpe gave an answer which on second thought I think is better, and requires less faff than the one I linked to.

Comment: Come to think of it, you're right. I would still mark it as a duplicate, to help future users browse through these questions.