# xlsread() thinks my 1-line CSV has 1048576 rows

Tags: matlab, csv, file-io

I wanted to use `[~, ~, temp] = xlsread('1.csv','A:A');` to get the first column of the 1-line CSV file `1.csv`.

`1.csv` contains just one line:

> 5B0E8795E18013D0FBC33558F0512832,3,7,1,Practice,Juicer,Juicer,true,false,2347.0,0

However the returned `temp` is a <1048576x1> cell. Shouldn't `temp` be a <1x1> cell?

The parameter `'A:A'` should return only the existing rows of the first column, as shown in the "Read a Column of Data" example in the [xlsread() documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html#bthgbe6). Since `temp` is a <1048576x1> cell, it seems like using `'A:A'` returns the entire column, including the non-existing rows (1048576 is the maximum number of rows in Microsoft Excel 2010).

Using `textscan()` works fine (= `datatemp` in the following snippet will have only 1 row):

```
fid = fopen('1.csv','r');
datatemp = textscan(fid, '%s %d %d %d %s %s %s %s %s %d %d', 'delimiter',',', 'CollectOutput',true)
fclose(fid);
```

However I don't understand why `xlsread()` fails to work properly. I use MATLAB R2012a 64-bit, Microsoft Excel 2010 and Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Why are you using `xlsread` to read a CSV file? Why won't you use `csvread`?

Comment: The xlsread() documentation http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html says: "On Windows® systems with Microsoft Excel software, xlsread reads any file format recognized by your version of Excel.", so I would expect it should work. Using textscan() is more tedious.

Comment: As for `csvread`, according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/10629794/395857 as well as the `csvread` documentation http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html: "csvread only work for numeric data.", so I cannot use it. Yes I was also surprised that `csvread` cannot handle non-numeric data.

Comment: Can you try saving that CSV file in XLS(X) format and test if `xlsread` works with that? If that's the case I'd rather forget about reading CSV files with `xlsread`. The documentation may be lying here.

Comment: I think it's a bug. I observe the same behavior on Win7 64 R2013a Excel2010. I would report to TMW and keep us updated.

Comment: @s.bandara Good idea, `xlsread()` does not work either when saving that CSV file in XLS(X) format, so it seems like Excel when opening the CSV thinks there are 1048576 rows, although the scrollbar in Excel acts as if there were only 1 row. But even when creating a new file from scratch in Excel,  `xlsread()` still doesn't work properly (see 1048576 rows). I have to go to a meeting now and I did these tests quickly but it seems like `xlsread()` doesn't like to be asked to read an entire column, e.g. `'A:A'`.

Answer (score 3):

That's actually how the Excel COM interface works, so you can't blame MATLAB :)

Here is a sample code that basically does what `xlsread` internally. You could write the code in VBScript/Powershell and get the same result...

```
%# create Excel COM server
Excel = actxserver('excel.application');

%# open file
Excel.workbooks.Open(which('1.csv'), 0, true);
Excel.Worksheets.Item(1).Activate();
Excel.Visible = true;

%# select first column
Excel.Range('A:A').Select();
val = Excel.Selection.Value();

%# close
Excel.Quit();
Excel.delete();
```

The variable `val` returned:

```
>> whos val
  Name            Size               Bytes  Class    Attributes

  val       1048576x1             71303224  cell
```

where all cells except the first one are NaNs:

```
>> val(1:3)
ans = 
    '5B0E8795E18013D0FBC33558F0512832'
    [NaN]
    [NaN]
```

---

I dont understand why you dont just use `textscan` to parse the file as text, which is much faster than invoking COM (Not to mention portable to other platforms other than Windows)

Comment: The confusion is introduced by the example, that's why the question in the first place. According to "[Read a Column of Data](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html#bthgbe6)" the expectations on the behavior are different.

Comment: I forget to say that the example you mentioned in the docs is using the first two output of `xlsread`, which are extracted from the third output `raw` by dropping those nan cells you see above, and filtered into numeric/text. So if you write: `[~,txt] = xlsread('1.csv','A:A');` you get what you expect..

Comment: Good point, however the xlsread() documentation http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html says: "If xlRange is specified, leading blank rows and columns in the worksheet that precede rows and columns with data are returned in `raw`.". This implies quite explicitly that empty rows after the data are not expected to be returned, even in the `raw` column. Regarding the use of `textscan()`, it is more verbose and anyway shouldn't preclude `xlsread` from working properly.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: I guess that's true to some extent, but I think they were referring to regular range notation like `A1:C5`. The `A:A` in Excel triggers this particular behavior of returning the entire column. Not to mention the recent [change](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/xlsread-functionality-change-in-r2012a/) in `xlsread`

Comment: @Amro Wow, thanks for the link, seems like it is better to avoid `xlsread` as much as possible!

Comment: that's what I usually try to do, except for actual XLS/XLSX files :)