# xlsread matlab changes values when load

Tags: matlab

I've to load the 2nd sheet of an xslx file.
I use

```
[~,~,a] = xlsread('pathfile/namefile.xlsx',2)
```

the correct output (the content of the xlsx file) is:

```
Subject C. R.
Age 81
Height  152 cm (5' 0")
Weight  57.6 kg (127.0 lbs)
Gender  Male
Handedness  Right Handed
Smoker  Smoker
Serial Number   7502880
BMI 24.93
```

but the content of my vector `a` is

```
'Subject'          'C. R.'    
'Age'              '81'                 
'Height'           '152 cm (5' 0")'     
'Weight'           '57.6 kg (127.0 lbs)'
'Gender'           'Male'               
'Handedness'       'Right Handed'       
'Very Light'       'Very Light'         
'Serial Number'    '7502880'            
'BMI'              '24.93'
```

You can see that in row 7 appears 'Very Light' 'Very Light'....how is it possible????
Path and name of the file are correct!
I run matlab on a linux machine

Comment: Could you post a (possibly trimmed) xls file which reproduces the error?

Comment: Hi Luis! what do you mean?
The xlsx file is the "correct output" that I posted before...
I just did copy and paste from the file..

Comment: I meant a link to the actual file, so that we can try

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3vXKJ_zYaCJQ3N2LTdFaW9Eczg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I should be able to load correctly sheet 2

Comment: Take the file down immediately and anonymize it. I am pretty sure you are (accidentally) sharing protected patient information. I don't know where you live but where I live that's a big no-no.

Comment: But yes - that is very puzzling. "Very light" appears on the next sheet (under definition of activity levels). I suspect you may have found a bug - either in Matlab, or Excel. Try saving the file in the "older" `.xls` format - it might fix it for you. If it does, report as a bug to both Matlab and Microsoft (with anonymized sample file).

Comment: It seems to work okay with Windows 7 + MATLAB R2013b + Microsoft Office 2010: http://pastebin.com/RPnCGUw1 (I changed some values for privacy)

Comment: Surprisingly, `[~,~,a] = xlsread('11.xls.xlsx',2,'', 'basic')` works too. I would have expected its behavior to be the same across different OS. So I guess `xlsreadBasic()` has some issues on Linux. Also FYI `xlsread()` has other issues, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/16700909/395857

Comment: Hi Franck, with  [~,~,a] = xlsread('11.xls.xlsx',2,'', 'basic') I have the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be due to using xlsread in basic mode (since you are on Linux), which technically doesn't support importing by worksheet number. You can specify the worksheet name instead:

```
[~,~,a] = xlsread('pathfile/namefile.xlsx','Subject Info')
```

If that doesn't work, have you tried it by simply saving the sheet as a separate excel file and importing?