# Matlab: reading rows of different formats from csv file

Tags: matlab, datetime, csv, file-io

I'm trying to read a csv file that contains data in format:

```
02/01/2012  03/01/2012  04/01/2012  05/01/2012  06/01/2012 09/01/2012 10/01/2012
1w  0.652   0.626   0.606   0.584   0.564   0.546   0.53
2w  0.738   0.716   0.7 0.68    0.662   0.645   0.628
3w  0.845   0.826   0.808   0.785   0.762   0.746   0.734
1m  1.005   0.988   0.97    0.951   0.93    0.912   0.894
2m  1.165   1.152   1.137   1.122   1.105   1.092   1.083
3m  1.343   1.333   1.319   1.303   1.288   1.276   1.267
4m  1.425   1.416   1.403   1.387   1.372   1.362   1.355
```

I've read the posts: 
[How to use "csvread" when the contents in the file have different formats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629691/how-to-use-csvread-when-the-contents-in-the-file-have-different-formats)

[Reading date and time from CSV file in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641519/reading-date-and-time-from-csv-file-in-matlab)

but I still cannot figure out how to read first row that contains strings representing dates and convert it into matlab date format.

Comment: How about using `fget1` http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html for the first line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
%# open file for reading
fid = fopen('file.csv', 'rt');

%# read first line and extract date strings
dt = textscan(fgetl(fid), '%s');

%# read the rest of the data
D = textscan(fid, '%s %f %f %f %f %f %f %f', 'CollectOutput',1);

%# close file
fclose(fid);

%# convert to serial date numbers
dt = datenum(dt{1}, 'mm/dd/yyyy')

%# place data in individual cells
D = [D{1} num2cell(D{2})]
```

The result:

```
dt =
      734900
      734929
      734960
      734990
      735021
      735113
      735143
D = 
    '1w'    [0.652]    [0.626]    [0.606]    [0.584]    [0.564]    [0.546]    [ 0.53]
    '2w'    [0.738]    [0.716]    [  0.7]    [ 0.68]    [0.662]    [0.645]    [0.628]
    '3w'    [0.845]    [0.826]    [0.808]    [0.785]    [0.762]    [0.746]    [0.734]
    '1m'    [1.005]    [0.988]    [ 0.97]    [0.951]    [ 0.93]    [0.912]    [0.894]
    '2m'    [1.165]    [1.152]    [1.137]    [1.122]    [1.105]    [1.092]    [1.083]
    '3m'    [1.343]    [1.333]    [1.319]    [1.303]    [1.288]    [1.276]    [1.267]
    '4m'    [1.425]    [1.416]    [1.403]    [1.387]    [1.372]    [1.362]    [1.355]
```

Comment: Cool. I had to modify it slightly ( add 'Delimiter' etc) but I got the idea! Thanks a lot!